# jhipster microservice gateway with multi-cluster ingress

Tags: jhipster, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a jhipster generated microservice gateway and application that I run in Google's GKE by using the jhipster kubernetes generator.  I have istio deployed in the kubernetes cluster and not using the jhipster-registry.

When I deploy the gateway with `ServiceType=Ingress`, the communication between the gateway and the application works great. I am trying to get up a GKE multi-cluster ingress which load balances the application deployed in clusters in different regions.

Google has a beta tool called kubemci which sets up all the plumbing for the load balancers. However, in order to use kubemci, the gateway needs to be deployed as a `NodePort` instead of `ClusterIP`. When I deploy with `ServiceType=NodePort`, I get errors when trying to create entities.

The error is:

```
translation-not-found[Http failure response for http://store.xxxx.com/product04/api/products?page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc: 404 Not Found]
```

I do not get this error when the app is deployed as a `ClusterIP` and I access it through the istio ingress gateway. Does anyone know what I need to do get the microservices to talk to the gateway when its defined as a `NodePort`?

Comment: 404 could be related with the LoadBalancer still being created, if you run  `kubemci get-status` what do you see?

Comment: Load balancer was fully operational.  I can navigate around the gateway but it seems the http request from the application to the gateway is not resolving when the gateway is defined as a NodePort.  The same app works fine in a single GKE cluster when the gateway is defined as ClusterIP.